# Pre-validating form before submitting

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation

I am trying to make something display (or not display depending on what they choose). But, I need to do that BEFORE validation. How could I do this? My code does that only AFTER pressing the submit button. But I need to pre-validate it, so that the colour red appears from the get go.

(note: I don't wanna use hardcoded CSS, since I need to use a similar code for display and display none).

```
if($('#amortization_years').val() == '' || $('#amortization_years').val() == 0 || $('#amortization_years').val() >= 36 || $('#amortization_months').val() >= 12 || ($('#amortization_years').val() == 35  && $('#amortization_months').val() > 0))

{
    $('#amortization_years').css('border', 'solid red 2px');
    $('#error_years').fadeIn(3000);
    $('#amortization_months').css('border', 'solid red 2px');
    $('#error_months').fadeIn(3000);
    valid = false;}
    else {($('#error_years').fadeOut(3000) && $('#error_month').fadeOut(3000));
}
```

**EDIT: reworked but still need help**

I worked on the content that @Aprillion linked me to. This is what I sort of need (reworked), which is for a dropdown menu.

In the end, there is a portion of the form (#16 from the dropdown menu) which NEEDS to appear ONLY if certain conditions are met (basically where if a person chooses the 1st answer, only then could he also pick the 16th question, which would appear inside the dropdown menu. So basically, if the person does NOT pick any item in the dropdown menu which contains 15 items (plus the 16th one), then he could NOT pick #16.

Here is the code I was reworking.

```
    <script>
            /*
The id for the thing
    sCat-<?php echo $numProj; ?><?php echo $numC ?>
    */
    window.onload=function(){
        var validate = function(evt){
            // your custom code, e.g.:
            valid = true;
            if ($('.16th').val() !== "sCat-<?php echo $numProj; ?><?php echo $numC ?>") {
                //valid = false;
                $('.16thup').css('display', 'none');
                //$('#a').addClass("invalid");
            } else {
                //$('#a').removeClass("invalid");
                $('.16thup').css('display', 'block');
            }
            //return valid;
        }

        $('#myform').change(validate);
        $('#myform').submit(validate);
        }

    </script>
```

Comment: Run the code at load or set it with CSS. What is the problem?

Comment: I also need to use it with display and display none. I tried running the code on load, which didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You can bind the validation to the [change](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Reference/Events/change) event as well as to [submit](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Reference/Events/submit).

http://api.jquery.com/change/

Comment: I was trying to understand what's written, but I don't understand how to use it :/

Comment: how did you bind the validation in OP to the submit event in the first place?

Comment: I used a form action to submit to the next page, while using javascript validation on that page (this above being the post action of the event).

Comment: aaah... there are plenty of examples how to do event handling, including in the jquery link above... but to get moving, have a look at http://jsfiddle.net/deathApril/ceWyK/, put your code inside `validate` function and try to make it work... and update your question if you have further problems..

Comment: Yes, I have read several things in the link you had provided. I tried a multiple of things, which failed. I didn't really understand much of what they were explaining. JavaScript isn't my strong suit.